# Get Microsoft Graph messages by flagStatus using OData $filter

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api

I'm writing Microsoft Graph OData query to get mail messages based on message flagStatus in order to reuse working query in my C# code. How correct query should look like?

Following example is tried in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)'s sample account where all messages have object `flag` with field `flagStatus = "notFlagged"`.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=flag/flagStatus eq 'notFlagged'
```

It is expected that all messages should be returned. But as a result empty array was given back.

If in query I change `eq` to `ne` to be

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=flag/flagStatus ne 'notFlagged'
```

then all messages are returned. But by me it is expected that here should be empty array in this case.

Considering that maybe `flag` object isn't ready for filtering, I also tried to `$expand` it

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=flag&$filter=flag/flagStatus eq 'notFlagged'
```

but got error message

> Property 'flag' on type 'microsoft.graph.message' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.

So probably `$expand` for flag filtering is not needed. But is it possible to filter by message's flag at all?

Also if consider situation that `flag` object could be null and also `flagStatus` inside could be null (at least in C# class `Microsoft.Graph.FollowupFlag` property `FlagStatus` is nullable), then how query should look like to meet full requrirement below?

Get messages whose

1. `flag` is `null`
2. or `flag/flagStatus` is `null`
3. or `flag/flagStatus` is `'notFlagged'`

Comment: What's funny I had the same problem and worked it around by comparing eq 'complete' or ne 'complete'. I have no idea why filtering by 'notFlagged' value does not provide a correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, probably is nullable as suggested. There's only three possible statuses according to the [followupFlag documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/followupflag?view=graph-rest-1.0), so I worked around it with a not equal and condition for the two other statuses, complete and flagged.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=flag/flagStatus ne 'flagged' and flag/flagStatus ne 'complete'
```